# useless annoying warnings in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

In my code I have many warnings for "dead code".
The problem is that I have code like this one

```
public void myMethod(final String text) {
    if(CONST_FLAG && something == true) {
       doMyMethod(text);
    }
}
```

CONST_FLAG is a build-configuration const. When CONST_FLAG is false I get the warning for the dead code. If I say that I want to suppress the warning I see a warning for an "unnecessary suppress" when the flag is true.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you do the work in else part when your CONST_FLAG is false. Like this

when you say like below I'm geting dead code warning

```
if(false) {
       doMyMethod(text);
    }
```

But like below I'm not getting that warning,

```
  private static final boolean CONST_FLAG = false;

if(CONST_FLAG) {
       doMyMethod(text);
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting the warning in that case

Comment: Actually I too am not getting the warning in the 2nd case.

Comment: Im not getting a warning on the second case neither, i didnt use supress warnings and my eclipse has the default configuration.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure the Eclipse not to show you warnings in certain situations, like `Dead Code`, `Unused Imports`, etc, using the below path: -

> Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/ Warnings
>   -> Potential Programming Problems -> Set **`Dead Code`** to Ignore.

Comment: But in this case I would not see dead code warnings at all. The reason why I want to suppress them in that cases is that tehy would hide more important cases

Comment: @delamere. More important cases like?

Comment: @delamere.. And in that case, you can follow the Sura's answer in this question. And then you can use `SuppressWarnings`

Comment: He said when he uses suppress warnings it gives him a warning if the flag is true. Not critical, but annoying

Comment: @Raeki.. Yeah because when the warning is not really there, then the `SuppressWarning` annotation will itself give a warning of unneccessary suppress.

Comment: @Downvoter.. Would you like to comment on your downvote? Please be confident enough to justify your downvote, if you are doing so, else don't do it.

Comment: @RohitJain +1 from me... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

```
public void myMethod(final String text) {
   boolean shouldDotit = something == true && CONST_FLAG;
   if(shouldDoIt) {
      doMyMethod(text);
   }
}
```

So I needed to use a local variable and to invert the order of the boolean checks